# (qt6 + postgres) Driver not loaded (macos)

Tags: postgresql, qt

I can't figure out how to either create a driver (as specified in the [documentation]), or specify the path to the driver (it is displayed as existing).

I'm trying to connect to the local Postgres installed from brew to the default path (`/opt/homebrew/var/pos...@15/data`), qt is installed in `users/murzabaev/Qt/`.

Output from the console.

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
```

Qt6.4, Postgres 15.1

I use qsqldatabase class for connect to db.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("pr8");
    db.setUserName("murzabaev");
    db.setPassword("*****");

    QMessageBox::information(0, "drivers", db.driverName());
```

I tried to find the file of the driver itself in the PostgreSQL and qt files. Also pointed out different patches for the .pro.

I know how to solve the problem on Windows or Linux, but I couldn't solve it on MacOS (ventura13.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install libpq and link in your project

Comment: ty for answer.
A little addition for others.
I found the drives in brew. 
command: brew install qt-postgresql 
after, in folder /opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt-postgresql/6.4.2 u can find the drivers you need

Comment: brew install libpq

Comment: new solution for сmake project:
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)